# signed and unsigned representation of data in memory?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

see the below code,

```
signed int a = 136; 
unsigned int b = -120; 

unsigned sum = a + b;
 printf("%d ", sum);
```

output-   `16`

according to my knowledge,

hex representation of

```
136 - ox88
-120 - ox88
```

1) SO IT SHOULD PRINT 0. ISN'T IT ?

2) how a -ve(signed) number is represented in memory as unsigned int ? is it like this,

```
-120 = 0xffffff88
136 = 0x00000088
```

if yes, in unsigned int range may have a value equal to "0xffffff88", so does it will conflict to each other ?

Can anyone explain the concept with example?(both signed and unsigned representation)

Comment: Read [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) first.

Comment: 136 - 120 = 16. What is surprising on that? Binary representation plays no role here.

Comment: You are omitting from the reasoning in 1) the step where you say “… and 0x88 + 0x88 = 0, therefore …”. Do you see the problem?

Comment: i know 2's compliment. but getting confused. how can we store a -ve value in unsigned int ? how it will be represented in memory?

Comment: 0x88 + 0x88 !=0, ok u r right Pascal. but it doesn't give 16. but in answer it is 16! how it calculated?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to guess about how things are represented in memory, and 2's complement arithmetic is endianness-agnostic.

Consider the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    signed int a = 136; 
    unsigned int b = -120; 

    unsigned sum = a + b;
    printf("a = 0x%x b = 0x%x sum = 0x%x\n", a,b, sum);
}
```

Output:

```
a = 0x88 b = 0xffffff88 sum = 0x10
```

In 2's complement, when we can sum `a` and `b` in binary without worrying about signs.

When we do the sum by hand, we will get `a + b = 0x100000010`. Since the first `1` overflows, it is simply dropped, leaving us `0x10`, which is `16`.

Comment: so unsigned int can store a -ve value same like signed int ? so doesn't it conflict with another value in unsigned int ? suppose in unsigned char ch = -1; so -1 will conflict with 255. isn't it ? because both of them have same representation 0xFF. can you please explaine?

Comment: @Melvin there is nothing wrong with the conflict you describe. A signed and unsigned integral type can certainly have the same representation.  The value is just how you interpret the bits

Answer (score 0):

your second binary representation is correct.
adding this 2 binary numbers together you will get 0x10 in hex or 16 in decimal (and an overflow)

-120 in unsigned int will have the value 4 294 967 176 in 4 byte unsigned int

Comment: so does does 4 294 967 176 conflict with another number in unsigned int range ?

Comment: what do you mean with conflict? each possible number has it's own unique binary representation in one data type, so there are no conflicts. There are only problems if you switch from one to another data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
0xffffff88 +
0x00000088
----------
0x00000010 => 16
```

Also 1 in front of the result is discarded.

The 1 in second to last position in the result is from the carry by adding 8 + 8.